# Task Scheduling in amazon EC2 ubuntu instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, task, schedule

I'm trying to run a python script every 2 minutes in an amazon EC2 ubuntu instance and i've tried a lot of things that just aren't working.

Could someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to provide more context and information if you want anyone to be able to help you. How are you trying to run the script (cron job?) and what error messages, if any, did you get?

Comment: @borfast I'm kind of a noob in ubuntu and I need to know how to periodically run a python script. I didn't get any error messages

Comment: OK, I'll write a more detailed answer to help you out.

Comment: @borfast If I use the print function will I see the console print it out?

Comment: You will not see anything printing it out because the script is not being executed in your console, it is being executed in the background. If you want to output something, you will need to write it to a log file, or send it somewhere else over the network, or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to use is cron, a Unix service that allows you to schedule commands to be executed at certain times or intervals.

It is based on a simple configuration text file, the crontab (from "cron table", as in, the table with scheduled commands), which coincidentally is also the name of the tool to edit the file.

In order to edit your user's crontab, use this command: `crontab -e`
This will open your crontab file in a text editor.

Three things you will want to keep in mind about cron:

1. You should specify the full path to your scripts, otherwise cron will not know where to find them.
2. There's a crontab for each user and the scheduled commands are executed as the user who owns the crontab file.
3. Cron's resolution doesn't go below the minutes, i.e., you can't execute something every X *seconds*.

This should work for you:

`*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/python /path/to/your/script.py`

I suggest you have a look here: http://corntab.com/
Look at the syntax and the examples, it should be enough to get you going, as well as help you create more crontabs.